# VS 2010 Compilation tips

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a vs 2010 WPF solution with 15 class projects and one main wpf project.
I compile first, then once its finished ( without making further code changes) I decide to Shift + f5 and whole solution compiles again? What a waste of time. Does anybody else experience this issue?

Comment: What do you have Shift-F5 bound to?

Comment: I assume you mean control f5 and you are compiling with debug = true

Answer (score 1):

Shift+F5 may force a rebuild of the solution.  Try F5, or Debug->Start Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If your having that issue you could remap shift +f5 to compile current project so you don't have to do the whole solution.  I think shift + f6 is compile current project by default.